# building a class method combining two classes with same parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two classes are related via a same parent

```
class Promoitem 
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :article, optional: true

class Cartitem 
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :cart

class Cart 
  belongs_to :shop

class Article
  has_many   :cartitems
  has_many   :promoitems
```

An existing controller method executes logic as follows:

```
valid_promo = Promoitem.where('shop_id = ? AND date_start <= ? AND date_end >= ? AND article_id = ?', @shop.id, Date.today, Date.today, cartitem.article_id ).first
if valid_promo
  api_price = valid_promo.price_promo
else
  api_price = cartitem.article.sell_price
end
```

but that makes the controller fat and this logic could reside in the `cartitem` model definition.
the goal is to write efficient model methods.

```
class Cartitem 
# scope is bad
  scope :price_promo, lambda { joins(:promoitems).where("date_start <= ? AND date_end >= ? AND article_id = ?", Date.today, Date.today, self.article_id) }

def valid_promo
  self.promoitems.price_promo
end

def api_price
  if self.valid_promo
    self.promoitems.price_promo
  else
    self.article.sell_price
  end 
end
```

The scope definition is wrong, as the relationship is via the article class.  Thus each class could have

```
  has_many :promoitems, through: :articles 
  has_many :cartitems, through: :articles
```

But how does that translate into a proper scope that is effective at querying as the controller method - or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is very awkward and would greatly benefit from some restructuring because this statement *"...as the relationship is via the article class."* is not technically true. The relationship is actually via the "article" and the "cart => shop" making it very awkward to query directly.

That being said under your current circumstances you should be able to use the following:

```
class Cartitem < ApplicationRecord 
  scope :with_promo_pricing, -> { 
    promo_table = PromoItem.arel_table
    promo_join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(promo_table,
                   promo_table
                     .create_on(
                         promo_table[:article_id].eq(arel_table[:article_id])
                         .and(promo_table[:shop_id].eq(Cart.arel_table[:shop_id])
                 ))
    joins(:cart, :article) 
      .joins(promo_join)
      .select(arel_table[Arel.star],
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ISNULL',
                [promo_table[:price_promo],
                Article.arel_table[:sell_price]]
              ).as('final_price')
            )
      .where(promo_items: {start_date: ..Date.today, end_date: Date.today..}) 
  } 
  def api_price
    attributes['final_price'] || self.class.where(id: self.id).with_promo_pricing.final_price
  end 
end
```

This should produce the following SQL

```
SELECT 
  cartitems.*,
  ISNULL(promoitems.price_promo,articles.sell_price) AS final_price
FROM 
  cartitems 
  INNER JOIN carts ON carts.id = cartitems.cart_id 
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.id = cartitems.article_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN promoitems ON promoitems.article_id = cartitems.article_id
    AND carts.shop_id = promoitems.shop_id
WHERE 
  promoitems.start_date <= '2023-03-07' AND 
  promoitems.end_date >= '2023-03-07'
```

You could also use this with a `Cart` which I assume has to be the intent e.g.

```
@cart.cartitems.with_promo_pricing
```

Comment: This is doubly pertinent.  Great insight into the creation of the scope and its SQL translation.  This will however remain on a pedagogical level, because, as you correctly point out, the relationships are convoluted (even with a has_many through defined).  Given the cartiem object is finalized on a given date (thus the date query), it makes more sense to create a column for its finalized promo_price and save a not-so-short trip to the db: all `self`, no `scope` ...